# AngularJS using routeprovider

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am using angular js and I am trying to use route provider to load multiple html pages on a single page application. However I declared my module, 
controller and in my html have a button that sends to the controller to redirect the html to the new partial. 
What am I doing wrong?

PS. I'm not sure how the imports work as in if I use it in one html do I get it in another? As well why can I only import one module into one file 
I get an injector error if I import it into two separate HTML files.

```js
//module.js

var mainM = angular.module('mainM', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

mainM.config(["$routeProvider"], function($routeProvider))
{
 $routeProvider
 .when('/', 
 {
  controller: "homeController",
  templateUrl : 'index.html'
 })
 .when('/signIn', 
 {
  controller: "controllSignIn",
  templateUrl : 'partials/MainPage/signIn.html'
 })
 .when('Website/index.html', 
 {
  controller: "controllSignUp",
  templateUrl : 'partials/MainPage/signUp.html'
 })
 .when('/newProject', 
 {
  controller: "controllNewProejct",
  templateUrl : 'partials/MainPage/newProject.html'
 })
}

//End of config routing -------------------------------------------------------

//Controllers
mainM.controller('controllSignUp', function($scope)
{
 //Submit Data for sign up
$scope.credentials = [
 {word: "Testing"},
 {word: "Hello"} 
 ]
 
 $scope.changeView = function () 
 {
        $location.path('/partials/MainPage/signUp.html');
  //$scope.uname += "123";
  alert('called');
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Sign up-->

<html lang = "en" ng-app ="mainM">

<head>
 <title>Project Buddy</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>   
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
 
 <script src="/scripts/module.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signUp.css" />
</head>

<body data-ng-app = "mainM">
 <div data-ng-controller="controllSignUp">
 <center>
  <!-- Sign Up -->
  <form action = "http://www.google.com/formsubmission" method = "POST">
    
    <label>Username:</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="uname" placeholder="Enter username" />
    </br>
    <label>Email Address:</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="ename" placeholder="Enter email address" />
    </br>
    <label>Password:</label>
          <input type="password" ng-model="psw1" placeholder="Enter Password" />
    </br>
    <label>Confirm Password:</label>
          <input type="password" ng-model="psw2" placeholder="Enter Password" />
    
          
          <button type="button" ng-click="signUpUser()">Sign Up</button>  
  </form >
 </center>
 </div>
</body>

</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- index -->
<html lang = "en">

<head>
 <title>Project Buddy</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>   
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- Drop down menu -->
 <div id = "dropDown" ng-controller = "controllSignUp">
  <button id = "SignUp" ng-click="changeView()">Sign Up</button><br/>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```